# Ampscript capture page URL before form

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way to capture the page URL of the page the user was on prior to them going to my CloudPage form and then use that  as an input for the redirect after the form is submitted?

Thanks

Comment: Please remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can access the referrer header, containing the url, using this Ampscript function:

```
SET @Referer = HTTPRequestHeader("Referer")
```

I would place the @referer variable in a hidden field, and pass it on upon submit, so the target page can redirect appropriately.